# Catching Network Errors with Codename One

Tags: java, codenameone

I have written an app with CNO that connects to a webservice using this piece of code...

```
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(connReq);
Map<String,Object> result = new JSONParser().parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(connReq.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));
return result;
```

The code works fine for all successful connections. However when there is a "500 Internal Server Error" all it does it display a dialog with "Cancel" and "Retry".

The problem is that I am deliberately firing a bad request at an endpoint as part of a test - but I don't seems to have any choice about how to handle a bad response.

The code gets to this line - NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(connReq); - and then dies.

Is there anyway to capture a fail and then carry on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to handle errors. Check out the [developer guide section on networking](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html) for a lengthy discussion.

A simple solution consistent with your approach is:

```
connReq.setFailSilently(true);
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(connReq);    

if(connReq.getResponseCode() == 200 || connReq.getResponseCode() == 202) {
    // success code here
} else {
    // fail code here...
}
```